# getting multiple syntaxerrors when installing django 1.4.3 on my windows 7 machine

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pip

I tried to install django 1.4.3 on my windows 7 machine which has Python 3.3 installed.

I used `pip install django` but got several SyntaxError: invalid syntax messages on installation.

An example would be:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

byte-compiling C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\unittest\case.py to c
se.cpython-33.pyc
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\unittest\case.py", line 327
    except SkipTest, e:
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

byte-compiling C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\unittest\loader.py to
loader.cpython-33.pyc
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\unittest\loader.py", line 92
    except Exception, e:
                    ^
```

can Django not run with Python 3.3? any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Django 1.5 is the first version of Django to support Python 3.

[source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/python3/)

Comment: The Python 3 support in Django 1.5 is experimental only.

Comment: Sure, but it's non-existent in earlier versions.

Comment: True, I just wanted to make sure he knew what he was getting himself into. :)

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem..
I got Python 3.3
the installation of Django 1.4.3 seems to have gone OK
but when I try to create a project folder I get syntax error messages...